# Spring Data Cassandra - Retrieve Rows Affected

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

Is it possible get the rows affected in the Update Statement?

```
public void removeCountry(String id,int version) throws VersionException {
    log.debug("Update row"+id);
    try {
        Update update = QueryBuilder.update("country");
        update.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
        update.with(QueryBuilder.set("destroyed", true));
        update.where(QueryBuilder.eq("id",id));
        update.where(QueryBuilder.eq("version",version));
        cassandraOperations.execute(update);
        //How to I know if the row was updated
        int rows = 0;//complete
        if (rows==0) throw new VersionException("Row does not been updated yet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
}
```

I am newbie with Cassandra, so I dont know if I can do that like a the JDBC Operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, given the distributed nature of Cassandra with varying levels of consistency, the short answer is NO.

Others have posted similar questions on SO before, for example...

[How to know affected rows in Cassandra(CQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611459/how-to-know-affected-rows-in-cassandracql)